# using variable class names instead of lots of if clauses?

Tags: java, android, class, interface

I'm trapped right now and don't know an easier solution to this, maybe you can help me out.

I have an Interface called Animal and lots of Animal Classes implementing it.
EDIT: The interface must be wrong then:

```
public interface Animals {
    Integer lifespan = 0;

    public Integer getLifespan();
}
```

In a function I get some random animal Object back and I want to get variables of it.

```
if (animal instanceof GuineaPig) {
            lifespan = ((GuineaPig) animal).getLifespan();
            age = ((GuineaPig) animal).getAge();
            value = ((GuineaPig) animal).getValue();
}
if (animal instanceof Rabbit) {
            lifespan = ((Rabbit) animal).getLifespan();
            age = ((Rabbit) animal).getAge();
            value = ((Rabbit) animal).getValue();
}
```

Now I need to have if clauses for every animal, there must be an easier way, right? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT2:
Full Interface and Classes:

```
public interface Animals {
final Integer id = 0;
Integer prize = 999999;
Integer value = 0;
Integer age = 0;
Integer lifespan = 0;


String[] colors = {
        "c_bw", "c_w", "c_brw"
};


String name = null;
String finalColor = null;


public String[] getColors();
public Integer getPrize();
public Integer getId();
public Integer getLifespan();
public Integer getAge();
public Integer getValue();
public String getName();
public String setName(String animalName);
public String setFinalColor(String finalColor);
}

class GuineaPig implements Animals {
private final Integer id = 0;
private Integer prize = 10;
private final Integer difficulty = 0; // easy
private final Integer licenceNeeded = 0;
private Integer value = 5;
private Integer age = 0;


private String[] colors = {
    "c_bw", "c_w", "c_brw"
};


private String name = null;
private String finalColor = null;

@Override
public Integer getPrize() {
    return prize;
}


public void setPrize(Integer prize) {
    this.prize = prize;
}

public Integer getDifficulty() {
    return difficulty;
}

public Integer getLicenceNeeded() {
    return licenceNeeded;
}
@Override
public String[] getColors() {
    return colors;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public Integer getLifespan() {
    return null;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return name;
}

public String getFinalColor() {
    return finalColor;
}

public String setFinalColor(String finalColor) {
    this.finalColor = finalColor;
    return finalColor;
}

public Integer getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Integer value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}

class Rabbit implements Animals {
private final Integer id = 1;
private Integer prize = 15;
private Integer lifespan = 30;
private Integer difficulty = 0; // easy
private final Integer licenceNeeded = 1;
private Integer value = 7;
private Integer age = 0;


private String[] colors = {
        "c_b", "c_w", "c_br"
};


private String name = null;
private String finalColor = null;

@Override
public Integer getPrize() {
    return prize;
}

public void setPrize(Integer prize) {
    this.prize = prize;
}

public Integer getDifficulty() {
    return difficulty;
}

public Integer getLicenceNeeded() {
    return licenceNeeded;
}
@Override
public String[] getColors() {
    return colors;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public Integer getLifespan() {
    return null;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return name;
}

public String getFinalColor() {
    return finalColor;
}

public String setFinalColor(String finalColor) {
    this.finalColor = finalColor;
    return finalColor;
}

public Integer getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Integer value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

Comment: all the if clauses have same functions like age, value.. not necessary u want if statements.. i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It wasn't the Interface at fault or the classes...

Apparently I used a raw ArrayAdapter instead of a generic one. With a generic adapter it let me use the methods... I don`t even understand why, but whatever...

Answer (score 6):

In your small code sample, you can simply let the `Animals` interface have `getLifespan()`, `getAge()` and `getValue()` methods, and avoid the casting and the if statements :

```
lifespan = animal.getLifespan();
age = animal.getAge();
value = animal.getValue();
```

You didn't show the definition of your interface, but based on your question, it's possible that the Animal interface already has all those methods.

EDIT :

Your `Animals` interface (BTW `Animal` would be a better name) only defines `getLifespan()`. If you add the other methods to it (assuming all the classes that implement this interface have these methods), you'll be able to call them without casting.

Comment: Thats what I thought, too, but it can not reslove the function then.

Comment: u could have commented this.. not an answer.. @Eran

Comment: @DanielScholz Is the `animal` variable of type `Animal`? If it is, it should work without casting. If, one the other hand, `animal` is of type `Object` (perhaps you are getting it from some raw collection type), you'll have to cast it to `Animal` first.

Comment: Yes it is of type Animals. I have it in a ListView:
 Animals animal = (Animals) getItem(position);

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I had. 
The interface defines the method and the classes have the getters and setters. But it wont let me do it without casting.

Comment: @DanielScholz the interface you posted in the question contains only one method. What about `getAge()` and `getValue()`?

Comment: They're in there, just like lifespan, I just took it out for reading purposes.

Comment: @DanielScholz It would be helpful if you post the full interface in the question.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I put in the whole Interface and Classes in the Edit. Hope you can see the thinking error I have, I'm really confused now

Comment: @DanielScholz Well, there are no `getAge()` and `getValue()` methods in the interface.

Comment: Right, I added it, but I still can not call animal.getLifespan(); on the animal object

Answer (score 1):

You are not trapped. You overlooked at your problem.

Since Animal is an Interface, you need not to cast them to respected Instance types. Just removing all the conditions and writing

```
        lifespan = animal.getLifespan();
        age = animal.getAge();
        value = animal.getValue();
```

That should work as you are doing programming with interfaces. No need to add conditions at all.

Comment: Thats what I thought, too, but it can not reslove the function then.

Comment: @DanielScholz Can you please update your post with Animal interface ?

Comment: I updated it and showed the interface the lifespan part

Comment: @DanielScholz Ok. Inorder to get rid of those conditions, move the methods getAge and getValue methods to Interface and let implement all other concrete class.

Comment: When I do that, I get and Error and Android Studio tells me to remove the method body. : / Why is that so?

Comment: @DanielScholz you should only declare the methods in the interface, the implementation stays in the classes implementing the Animal interface.

Comment: Won't work. I only get an error in the function, to remove the method body.
And an error in the classes telling me they need getter and setter methods for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use abstraction:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract int getAge();
    abstract int getValue();
...
}
```

And implements this methods in Rabbit(etc) classes or you can implement them in Animal class and just extend it.

Answer (score 0):

you should declare getLifespan(), getAge() and getValue() methods in Animal interface. And then can use this:

```
Animal animal = new Rabbit(); //for example. Can change to new GuineaPig()
lifespan = animal.getLifespan();
age = animal.getAge();
value = animal.getValue();
```